# How to add an object to xml in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I created XML file as a database for objects that I created (that called "triple").
When I try to add another line of a new object (of the same type) it deletes the previous line.
How do I add without deleting? (under the previous line)

Here is the code:

```
public class RDB {
    File file;
    String filepath;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller;


    RDB(){
        filepath = "RDB.xml";
        file = new File(filepath);      
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(triple.class);
            jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    void addToXml(triple t){
        try {
            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(t, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(t, System.out);

              } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        RDB r = new RDB();
        r.addToXml(new triple(1,2,3));
        r.addToXml(new triple(4,5,6));

    }
```

And the triple class look like this:

```
public class triple implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private double x, y;
    private int z;

    triple(double x , double y, int z){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please use Java naming convention, i.e., "triple" class should be named "Triple" class.

Answer (score 0):

You are marshalling one object per time. You're overwritting the file at each call to addToXml().

Please, try to implement a class that has an array of 'triple' and then marshal that class.

Comment: Or you can open file in append mode :)

Comment: @svasa I don't know if it's possible to open a binary file in append mode (in this case of Apache POI). I think it's not possible. Do you have any information about it? Thanks

Comment: you can't open xml file in append mode? what does it have to do with Apache POI? you do it with java.io

Comment: @svasa (I'm sorry, I made a mistake.. I mean JAXB, not Apache POI) JAXB abstracts the access to XML file, so we don't need to handle texts directly.  We just handle objects in memory. It's not recommended to read/write text directly... it's subjected to mistakes and errors. If we have JAXB, it's better to use it correctly. It's far easier and safe to follow this recommendation above: please create your container class and you can marshal/unmarshall it at one hit. Hope this helps. Please imagine a huge and complex XML: it's not good to handle it manually without a JAXB mapping.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. JAXB abstracts the access to XML. If you want JAXB to write to xml do you want to know the location of xml file or not at minimum? and do you need to create a File object/File stream or not? In my answer it is just creating a stream in append mode. You are saying - encapsulate everything in one single class, what if I cannot ? I have two classes in two different packages and I want them to written to the same common xml. How to do that?

Comment: @svasa First, you need to define a class that will be your root element. And then, you must structure it accordingly to the format of XML you need to write/read. To update it, you need to read it from a file to memory via JAXB, change its properties/objects/arrays and then write it to the file again. We usually do this with JAXB, that helps us to maintain structure as a contract (XSD). The classes in the properties/objects/arrays of your root element can be from different packages, it's not a problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you under the impression that I want to insert xml data into it manually?. I just wanted to append to an existing file. I still would use JAXB to insert/update xml elements ofcourse sticking to XSD. Anyway thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileOutputStream to write to xml in append mode like:

```
OutputStream out = FileOutputStream( file, true);
```

then use `jaxbMarshaller.marshal( t, out );`

Make sure to properly close streams after you are done.